# Как уменьшить количество запросов?

Tags: php, sql

Доброго всем времени суток.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*), sum(q), sum(w), sum(e), sum(r) FROM zakaz WHERE d<'$d' AND c>'$c' AND a='$a' AND z='01'",$db);
```

Таких запросов у меня "много", с разницей только в z= 01, 02, 03, .... 99. Можно ли как-то уменьшить количество запросов?

P.S. Т.е. не записать это в цикл, что короче, а снизить кол-во запросов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*), sum(q), sum(w), sum(e), sum(r) FROM zakaz WHERE d<'$d' AND c>'$c' AND a='$a' AND z IN ('01','02','03')",$db);
//в скобках узказываем все необходимые значения для z
```

**Добавлено:**

```
    //имеем массив 
    $z = array('01','02','03');
    //инициализируем массивчик куда будем складировать вывод.
    $out = array();
    //формируем строку запроса:
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*), sum(q) as sum_q, sum(w) as sum_w, sum(e) as sum_e, sum(r) as sum_r FROM zakaz WHERE d<'$d' AND c>'$c' AND a='$a' AND z IN ('".implode("','",$z)."') GROUP BY z";
    //обращаемся к базе
    $result = mysql_query($query,$db);
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //выводим результат:
    echo $row['sum_q'];  
    //записываем в выходной массив целиком строку
    $out[] = $row;
    //либо какое то одно значение
    $out[] = $row['sum_q'];
      }
```

Comment: После запроса, мне охота получить результаты запроса. По скольку я не знаю как сделать запрос, и спросил об этом, можно было догадаться, что получить результат запроса более сложного, для меня тоже будет проблематично (логические выводы КЭП'а). Как же получить значения запроса после этого?

Comment: Странные у вас логические выводы. Результат запроса получается одинаково, и нет прямой связи со сложностью запроса.

Comment: я узнал много нового, уже понятнее, но не до конца. вот, что я написал с верху 495 переменных (95 сумм количества  и 380 сумм значений), ну и по ЖЕЛАНИЮ, я могу их "echo". в случае с while я просто смогу увидеть результат.

как результат приравнять к переменным то? (вывод НЕ интересует)

Comment: исправлено

Comment: написал $out[03] = $row['sum_q']; и после цикла echo $out[03]; ... при каких то значениях (допустим 03, 04 ...) выдает правильную сумму, при каких то сумма не правильная. в любом случае спасибо, дальше буду сам думать

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*), sum(q), sum(w), sum(e), sum(r), z FROM zakaz WHERE d<'$d' AND c>'$c' AND a='$a' GROUP BY z",$db);
```

Теперь запрос не будет выполняться в цикле, этот цикл будет использоваться при чтении результатов. Если нужно как-то ограничить поле z, то используйте условие, допустим "z BETWEEN '01' AND '99'"

Comment: после своей уонструкции у меня шло: $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);  $sumq01 = $myrow['sum(q)']; эта переменная если z=01. а теперь как?

Comment: `print_r($myrow);` и все увидите

Comment: Array ( [0] => 0 [COUNT(*)] => 0 [1] => [sum(q)] => [2] => [sum(w)] => [3] => [sum(e)] => [4] => [sum(r)] => )
 прописал, все равно не дошло.