# что есть сложный запрос к БД ?

Tags: php, mysql

доброго всем времени суток господа.

есть так называемая ассоциация - "сложный запрос" к БД mysql. слово сложный... понятие растяжимое, допустим:

```
$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0,1"); // запрос
$massiv = mysql_fetch_array($zapros);                   // все что нашли
$massiv["field"];                                       // нужный кусочек
```

это простейший запрос (знаю, знаю, словами дилетанта объяснил...). можно накрутить еще условия WHERE, ORDER BY, условий может быть несколько (AND) - но все ли это?

прошу разъяснить мне, что есть "сложный запрос" ? и как использовать результат запроса. (хотелось бы с каким то описанием) можно ли одним запросом обратиться к нескольким БД?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Долго терпел писать или не писать  ответ, но не смог пересилить себя, в итоге все таки напишу.

Из того что написали предыдущие ораторы мне только подытожить остается.

Вопрос
    что есть сложный запрос к БД ?

Тут можно долго дискутировать.
С одной стороны сложный запрос к БД это запрос который по сути должен возвращать только одно значение или одну колонку из таблицы.
Представим что у нас есть таблица в которой **1 миллион записей**, допустим, **15 полей разных типов**, и Blob к тому же, где хранятся, допустим картинки до **5Мб**. Нам нужно получить название картинок,300 картинок начиная с 900 000 и заканчивая 900 300 они находятся в поле **name_picture** но запрос выглядит так

```
SELECT * FROM af_products WHERE d_upload>'2010-11-02' and d_upload<'2011-12-22' ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 900000,300
```

Тут выберутся все поля. Все с математикой дружат? допустим средний размер фотки 3,5Мб умножаем на 300 выбранных записей 1Гб. просто так выбрали из БД, время выполнения скрипта может и небольшое, но вот то кол-во выбранных полей неправильно. Но скорее всего этот запрос относится не к сложности запроса, а к тупости разработчика, которому пофиг на оптимизацию, даже и такую простую, как выборка только нужных полей из таблиц.

Сложный запрос к БД это и такой запрос. Затрагиваем несколько таблиц + производим выборку с помощью LIKE. Наверное сложный, хоть и выполняется он достаточно быстро, при 10К записях в таблице. Это код из модуля для ModX, писал словарь.

```
SELECT dic.name as dic_name, dic.id as dic_id,dw.id,dw.alias,dw.short_desc, dw.name AS d_name 
    FROM `dictionary_word` dw 
    LEFT JOIN `word` ww ON ww.id=dw.word_id 
    LEFT JOIN `dictionary` dic ON dw.dictionary_id=dic.id 
    where ww.name like '%".$_GET['search']."%' and dic.id=".$_GET['sid']." and dic.public=0
```

Всё-таки из общенародного и общепринятого ***сложный*** запрос к БД это запрос в котором затрагиваются несколько таблиц, т.е. происходит JOIN. Но на практике сложность запроса формируется многими факторами, если взглянуть на первый запрос, то там глупость разработчика, во втором запрос большой, но выполняется быстро. Всё таки сложный запрос - это тот который занимает определенно больше времени на исполнение на которое вы расчитывали, и подразумевает оптимизацию, если она возможна. Причем возможна несколькими способами, либо изменением условий, либо разбитием на несколько более простых. Экспериментировать можно много,тут главное правильный окончательный эффект.
так же если смотреть на любой запрос с

```
LIMIT 900000,300
```

Мы понимаем что сначала выберутся все 900300 записей и только потом отсортируются нужные нам 300 - это тоже сложный запрос к БД, хотя и человеческий фактор чтобы так не делать присутствует.

```
можно ли одним запросом обратиться к нескольким БД?
```

В приницпе можно, а особенно можно если они скажем так в одной БД и разбиты префиксами. По сути получаются несколько БД, т.е. и сайтов в одной БД может быть много, таблицы одинаковы различаются только префиксами, для сайтов визиток - это вариант.
А по сути нельзя ведь подключиться мы можем к одной БД. т.е.

```
$link1=mysql_connect();
$link2=mysql_connect();
```

2 разных подключения, и запрос предназначенный для БД 1 не выполнится для БД 2.
Так что думаю тут выбрать правильный ответ тяжеловато, они по сути своей все правильны, ну или хотя бы смотрят в нужную сторону.

у меня как обычно всё :)

ps 3341 буквы / 538 слова

Answer (score 3):

Ну, один из вариантов:

```
SELECT `t1`.`field1`,`t1`.`field2`,`t2`.`field3` from `table1` as `t1` join left `table2` as `t2` on `t1`.`some_key1` = `t2`.`some_key2`
```

Либо запрос с подзапросом:

```
SELECT `t1`.`field1` from (select * from `table2` where `field1`='somevalue') as `t2` where `t1`.`field5`=`someothervalue`
```

А я всегда говорил товарищу [@Expert](/users/6/expert), что нельзя учить программирование, пытаясь все переводить на русский... Слово сложный тут в значении "Составной" в противоположность простому - "Атомарному".

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос из разряда философических или религиозных :-) Сложность запросов познается в сравнении, как и все в этом мире относительно, поэтому:

*Сложный запрос - запрос который потребляет *больше* ресурсов у SQL сервера чем простой запрос*

Так например простой запрос:

```
select * from table where id=1
```

Сложный запрос:

```
select
    t.id, t.article
from
   table t
   left join tag t1 on (t.id = t1.t_id)
where
   t1.id in (2,3,4)
group by
   t.id
having
   count(t.id) = 3
```

Comment: вауу!!! то, что искал. вот это вызывает у меня сложность, прежде всего в незнании 8-) можно по подробнее объяснить, что с чем едят в этом запросе?

Comment: В сложном запросе поиск материалов по тегам, то есть таблица `t` это материалы, а `tag` таблица-связка материал.id <-> тег.id, и соответственно результатом работы запроса будет список материалов у которых установлены все три тега id = 2,3,4

Answer (score 0):

Для меня сложный запрос - это когда приходится оперировать огромным количеством данных, здесь нужно учитывать каждую мелочь, и не уронит ли вообще такой запрос сервер.

Comment: Тоесть

    select * from table

Где table - 1 Тб - это сложный запрос?

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю, "сложный запрос" - это запрос с затрагиванием нескольких таблиц.

Answer (score 0):

Сложный запрос - запрос в котором используется много разных конструкций, ключевых слов, работа с несколькими таблицами.

Answer (score 0):

в том что "составной" запрос вызывает кипение мозга - это абсолютно правильное замечание. но встречается и вот такое: [одна из моих тем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33240/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)

- на мой взгляд, сложно. сложно т.к. необычно. с тем, что запросы бывают составные - разобрались, кстати спасибо за ответ. давайте поговорим, на счет разнообразности этих запросов. вот допустим этот самый "implode", до сих пор для меня не сгрызаемый гранит науки. может ли кто привести пример работы с ним, или еще, с чем то, что в теме не расписали?

Comment: вы об этом implode ? http://php.su/functions/?implode

Answer (score 0):

А может быть сложный это когда начинается пробег по записям регулярками ? Тогда для сервера это точно будет сложно даже при небольших задачах